# Exception_Record in python2.5 problem

Tags: python, winapi

I'm using Python2.5 & the following code produce 2 errors.
Can any body help me?

```
class EXCEPTION_RECORD(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("ExceptionCode", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionFlags", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionRecord", POINTER(EXCEPTION_RECORD)),
        ("ExceptionAddress", LPVOID),
        ("NumberParameters", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionInformation", ULONG_PTR * EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS)]
```

Python Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python25\my_debugger_defines.py", line 70, in <module>
    class EXCEPTION_RECORD(Structure):
  File "E:\Python25\my_debugger_defines.py", line 74, in EXCEPTION_RECORD
    ("ExceptionRecord", POINTER(EXCEPTION_RECORD)),
NameError: name 'EXCEPTION_RECORD' is not defined
```

Microsoft Document:

```
The EXCEPTION_RECORD structure describes an exception. 

typedef struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD { // exr  
    DWORD ExceptionCode; 
    DWORD ExceptionFlags; 
    struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *ExceptionRecord; 
    PVOID ExceptionAddress; 
    DWORD NumberParameters; 
    DWORD ExceptionInformation[EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS]; 
} EXCEPTION_RECORD;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've done a `from ctypes import *` (terrible practice, as one is reduced to guess where all those identifiers like `DWORD` are actually coming from!-) but missed a crucial short passage in [ctypes.Structure's docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure):

> It is possible to define the *fields*
>   class variable after the class
>   statement that defines the Structure
>   subclass, **this allows to create data
>   types that directly or indirectly
>   reference themselves**:

```
class List(Structure):
    pass
List._fields_ = [("pnext", POINTER(List)),
                 ...
                ]
```

> The *fields* class variable must,
>   however, be defined before the type is
>   first used (an instance is created,
>   sizeof() is called on it, and so on).
>   Later assignments to the *fields*
>   class variable will raise an
>   AttributeError.

So, simply applying this bit of the docs to your code, you need to change that code into:

```
class EXCEPTION_RECORD(Structure):
    pass
EXCEPTION_RECORD._fields_ = [
        ("ExceptionCode", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionFlags", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionRecord", POINTER(EXCEPTION_RECORD)),
        ("ExceptionAddress", LPVOID),
        ("NumberParameters", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionInformation", ULONG_PTR * EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can't refer to a class type while defining a class, e.g.:

```
>>> class C:
    f = C



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    class C:
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 2, in C
    f = C
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

However, you can work around that by doing this:

```
>>> class C:
    pass

>>> C.f = C
```

I would re-write your code as follows:

```
class EXCEPTION_RECORD(Structure):
    pass

EXCEPTION_RECORD._fields_ = [
        ("ExceptionCode", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionFlags", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionRecord", POINTER(EXCEPTION_RECORD)),
        ("ExceptionAddress", LPVOID),
        ("NumberParameters", DWORD),
        ("ExceptionInformation", ULONG_PTR * EXCEPTION_MAXIMUM_PARAMETERS)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A class can reference itself in the `__new__` or `__init__` methods.

```
class Test(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        inst = object.__new__(cls)
        inst.me = Test
        return inst
```

or:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.me = Test
```

Or, if you wanted to really get fancy you could use a `__metaclass__`.